# Cannot run python in VS Code

Tags: python

Edit: TL;DR: Not the Code itself is the problem, the error message is. (Look at the picture/link)

I'm new to programming. Straight to the point: I cannot run my program because of *"& cannot be processed syntactically at this point"* and i really don't know how to fix it. I already tried a new debugger, reinstalled all expansions, uninstalled VS Code with everything and reinstalled it "clean"... and it still won't work. I searched for hours now... and I still didn't find a solution to this problem.

Btw.: I had first written the whole program on my calculator in math class and it worked perfectly fine, after that I copied it in into VS Code and now it doesn't work. The calculator uses MicroPython v1.9.4

The code, if it's needed, I originally tried (and where the same probleme occurs) is:

```
import math

def v(a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3):
  ma=a1*b1+a2*b2+a3*b3
  if ma==0:
    print("Orthogonal")
  m1=math.sqrt(a1**2+a2**2+a3**2)
  m2=math.sqrt(b1**2+b2**2+b3**2)
  cosg=ma/(m1*m2)
  g=math.acos(cosg)/math.pi*180
  if g>90:
    g=180-g
  print(g)

  x=a2*b3-a3*b2
  y=a3*b1-a1*b3
  z=a1*b2-a2*b1
  print("N(",x,"|",y,"|",z,")")
```

As I said: I'm new and I'm very excited to learn programming and all around it. So i would be very thankful if someone can help me.

[View of an easy probleme, where the same error occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCD4L.png)

Comment: Click "select python interpreter" on the bottom left, and select your python installation. If you don't have it installed first go download it https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: Have you tried not putting `&` at the beginning of your terminal command?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Im not adding it, that's the problem... look here for a video of my problem: https://youtu.be/v5SfdKDxmAc

Comment: @Scrapper142 Yes, Python is installed and correctly selected, no worries here. ^^ Edit: I correctly selected it before i answered your comment.